# powermock+easymock+testng for testing a final class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, easymock, powermock

Using these dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-module-test-easymock-testng</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my code, where Dispute is a class of type final.

```
 @PrepareForTest(Dispute.class)
        public void testProcessChargebackUpdates() {
            final List<BraintreeGateway> credentials = new LinkedList<BraintreeGateway>();
            credentials.add(credential);

    //      Dispute dispute = control.createMock(Dispute.class);
            Dispute dispute = PowerMock.createMock(Dispute.class);
}
```

Gives cannot instantiate final class.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to mock the final class?

Comment: yes, its a third part dependency.

Comment: You're not just missing the: `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` from the top of the test class are you?

Comment: That is a junit annotation and not testng.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is there. Are you not running your tests with JUnit? Either way, you need to run PowerMock tests with the PowerMockRunner in order for it to be able to instrument the classes correctly. If nothing else, the documentation says you need to use it when [mocking a final class](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal)

Comment: @DanTemple thanks for your suggestion it dis work when I use PowerMockRunner but that is part of the jnuit-powermock module, I was looking to do my testing in testng

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread testng as testing. My apologies.

Comment: Having a browse around at some other SO questions, it looks like you're supposed to extend PowerMockTestCase when running the tests under testNG. This [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage) also looks to be relevant for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Excellent! Be sure to add your solution as an answer for anyone having similar issues in the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you need these dependencies :

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-module-test-easymock-testng</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you need this in your class, @Prepare annotation with the final class to be mocked, as
well as the getObjectFactory method to be defined in the class.

```
@PrepareForTest(Dispute.class)
public void testProcessChargebackUpdates() {
    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }
}
```